# GET a URL from Form Input & Load Window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with an URL that outputs this info:

[image]

I have a form with POST for 'name' & 'email'

I have an action on the form set to a thank you page.

what I am stuck on is how to GET the URL parameters and then get the information from the API link above and then go to the thank you page. I am using jQuery/AJAX to get to where I need.

How do I get the user to the API url and then to the thank you page?

Comment: Cue the "where is your code?" statement, but seriously, what have you tried?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some basic code to validate form data and redirect would be:

```js
$('[data-validate]').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisForm = $(this);
    var validateUrl = thisForm.data('validate');
    var redirectUrl = thisForm.attr('action');
    var dataToSend = thisForm.serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: validateUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: dataToSend,
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.success) {
                window.location = redirectUrl;
            } else {
                alert('Error!');
            }
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="thank-you.html" data-validate="validate.php">
    <p>
        <input name="name" placeholder="Name" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery/Ajax promise to send the POST request, wait for the server to respond and then navigate to Thank you page. Sample Code :

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", email: "John.Doe@email.com" }
})
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log( data );
    // navigate to Thank you page
  });
```

More information here : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/